# How to enter the zero in front of numbers in excel?

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I have an application written in C# which extracts the data from Datagridview to excel. My problem is when I have a number like 010498 when I export to excel become 10498, without the zero (0) at the beginning. I want there to be zero (0). Is there any possible solution, either writing code in C # within the application or via excel?
Thanks and sorry for bad English.

[image: In the Datagridview]

[image: After export to excel]

In the first picture seems to datagridview and in the second picture how after export to excel. In cells A3, F3, F4 missing zero (0) at the beginning. Any Solution how i can fix it? Thanks.
Code of Export to Excel.

```
private void excel_toolstripmenuitem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = null;
        try
        {
            // instantiating the excel application class
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook currentWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet currentWorksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)currentWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
            currentWorksheet.Columns.ColumnWidth = 18;
            if (dg1.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                currentWorksheet.Cells[1, 1] = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
                int i = 1;
                foreach (DataGridViewColumn dgviewColumn in dg1.Columns)
                {
                    // Excel work sheet indexing starts with 1
                    currentWorksheet.Cells[2, i] = dgviewColumn.Name;
                    ++i;
                }
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range headerColumnRange = currentWorksheet.get_Range("A2", "AY2");
                headerColumnRange.Font.Bold = true;
                headerColumnRange.Font.Color = 0xFF0000;
                int rowIndex = 0;
                for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < dg1.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
                {
                    DataGridViewRow dgRow = dg1.Rows[rowIndex];
                    for (int cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < dgRow.Cells.Count; cellIndex++)
                    {
                        currentWorksheet.Cells[rowIndex + 3, cellIndex + 1] = dgRow.Cells[cellIndex].Value;
                    }
                }
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range fullTextRange = currentWorksheet.get_Range("A1", "AY" + (rowIndex + 1).ToString());
                fullTextRange.WrapText = true;
                fullTextRange.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;
            }

            using (SaveFileDialog exportSaveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog())
            {
                exportSaveFileDialog.Title = "Save as";
                exportSaveFileDialog.Filter = "Microsoft Office Excel Workbook(*.xls)|*.xls";

                if (DialogResult.OK == exportSaveFileDialog.ShowDialog())
                {
                    string fullFileName = exportSaveFileDialog.FileName;

                    currentWorkbook.SaveAs(fullFileName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, misValue, false, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlUserResolution, true, misValue, misValue, misValue);                      
                    currentWorkbook.Saved = true;
                    MessageBox.Show("The export was successful", "Export to Excel", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Exception", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (excelApp != null)
            {
                excelApp.Quit();               
                excelApp = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Make it a string or set the format to "000000".

Comment: @HansPassant via excel or via C# code?

Comment: @HansPassant Can you give me some code example (i am new). And thanks for the help.

Comment: I can't work with a screenshot, post code.

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry, you have right. I post the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Way 1**

```
currentWorksheet.Cells[rowIndex + 3, cellIndex + 1] = 
"'0" + dgRow.Cells[cellIndex].Value;
```

**Way 2**

```
Case 1
```

I believe your datagrid cell can have numbers of different lengths for example `0001234`, `00123`. So if you want to retain the numbers as they are in datagrid then don't set a prefixed format like `0000000`. Use Way 1 or individually format the cells. One more way I can think of is to store the DG cell's value in an `int` variable and then use `.PadLeft` after taking into account the length of DG cell's value. So a number like `0000123` will have a length of `7`. However in an `int` variable it will be stored as `123` (length - 3). All you have to do is use `.PadLeft` with `7-3=4 zeros` and then store the result string in the excel cell.

```
Case 2
```

If you want all numbers to be stored as the same length with a format say `00000000` then use this code.

```
//~~> This will format Column 1 with "00000000"
currentWorksheet.Columns[1].NumberFormat = "00000000";
```

PS: Tested in Excel 2010 + VS 2010 Ultimate

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly with the second way because I wanted to specific columns with same length.<br>
Do you know how to solve the issue with the date? I tried `currentWorksheet.Columns[5].NumberFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"` but it did not work. Thanks again.

Comment: Exception: It is not possible to set the NumberFormat property of the class Range.

Comment: Do you think is problem from DateTimePicker properties? because format option is Custom. I can show you a picture of properties if you want.

Comment: are you inputting the value first and then applying the format or the reverse?

Comment: Date picker? I was under the impression that you are exporting the data from the DGV date cell. If this is not the case then your new query should go as a fresh question in a new thread.

Comment: I fill data in a form, then displays them in a DGV and then export them from the DGV.

Answer (score 2):

```
   currentWorksheet.Cells[...] = dgRow.Cells[cellIndex].Value;
```

I'm guessing that would be the relevant line of code where you enter the number into the cell.  Assign the NumberFormat property to force Excel to display the extra leading 0:

```
   currentWorksheet.Cells[rowIndex + 3, cellIndex + 1].NumberFormat = "000000";
```

Assuming you wanted "010498".

Answer (score 1):

You can put an apostrophe before the number in Excel to keep leading zeroes.

```
'010498
```

You can still do arithmetic operations on numbers with a leading `'`.

If you know the length of the numbers (i.e., the numbers will always be six digits like your example), then you can also format cells with a Custom Number Format of all 0s (e.g. `000000`).

[image: Custom Number Format]

Comment: Is there any way to save it to excel so you do not have to do this every time?. Before opening the excel, cells A3-A100, F3-F100, G3-G100 is custom formated like your example.

Comment: + 1 Nicely explained with images.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a DataTable you need to Take another DataTable and then you need to iterate through entire cells in the datatable and prepend the cells text with space i.e with '&nbsp';.We cannot modify the rows in the same table because it will throw an exception saying "Collection was Modified".We have to take a new datatable.

Consider the following code.

```
    //To get the result with leading zero's in excel this code is written.
        DataTable dtUpdated=new DataTable();
        //This gives similar schema to the new datatable
        dtUpdated = dtReports.Clone();
            foreach (DataRow row in dtReports.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dtReports.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    string oldVal = row[i].ToString();
                    string newVal = "&nbsp;"+oldVal;
                    row[i] = newVal;
                }
                dtUpdated.ImportRow(row); 
            }
```

We can bind this updated table to datagrid so that it can be useful for Excel Conversion.

Answer (score 1):

After spending a couple of hours, I managed to fix the issue and successfully displayed the value "099999" in Excel instead of "99999".

Here's a brief explanation on how you can achieve the same and fix the issue:

1. Instead of using the property to set the value, use the function "SetValue(...)". My mistake was using the property, and once I changed it to the function, it worked perfectly.

Avoid assigning the value like this:

```
_worksheet.Cell(1, 1).Value =  "099999";
```

Instead, assign the value using the function::

```
_worksheet.Cell(1, 1).SetValue("099999");
```

After assigning the value, set the DataType of the cell using another function:

```
_worksheet.Cell(1, 1).SetDataType(XLDataType.Text);
```

Happy coding!

[image]